# How can I get element of value, when I click their button in MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a status in the dashboard and want to change its status. I need when I click it, the state will change its value.

My component

```
   <MenuItem>
              <Button
                fullWidth
                onClick={handleChangeStatus}
              >
                <Typography value={"pending"} sx={{ color: "#488C6E" }}>
                  pending
                </Typography>
              </Button>
            </MenuItem>
```

State and function

```
  const [changeStatus, setChangeStatus] = useState(data.status);
  const handleChangeStatus = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
    setChangeStatus(e.target.value);
  };
```

The main problem is that the console looks `e.target`. For example, if I click it, the console shows:

```
<p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 css-rzm8ko-MuiTypography-root" value="pending">pending</p>
```

but if I write `e.target.value`, it gives `undefined`

Comment: may instead of using `value={"pending"}` use `title={"pending"}`.
then `e.target.title` .
The value attribute specifies the `value` of an `<input>` element.

Comment: @UmairFarooq Yes, it works. Thank you very much. I confuse ```Typography``` with ```TextField```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use "value" prop in Typography. Please click [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/) link to see which props you can use in Typography.

I didn't understand what you want to do. But you can try this:

```
<Typography sx={{ color: "#488C6E" }}>
  {pending}    
</Typography>
```

Comment: ```Typography``` ile ```Textfield```i karışdırmışım. ```value```ni ```title```a deyişdirdiyimde sorun çözüldü. Buradan yardımcı oldular